# Twilio Request URL- JSON?

Tags: twilio

On my Twilio number I have a Request URL configured for Messaging. The problem is I need the HTTP Post from Twilio in json but there doesn't seem to be a way to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Twilio developer evangelist here.

Unfortunately there will be no way for you to configure Twilio to post a JSON request to your server. What you can do however is post to a different server that will take that request, turn it into JSON and then make a request to your original endpoint with a JSON packet.

That's obviously if you can't just convert the POST request into JSON on your original server, which is preferable.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks! I figured a way to convert it on my own side. Just for more info incase anyone stumbles upon this later. This is for the AWS API Gateway which prefers JSON. However, you can create a mapping template to convert url encoded post data to json:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=673012&tstart=0#673012

Comment: So in what format do we receive data from twilio. I configured my endpoint which accepts json. But its not working.

Comment: You will get a post request with all the formfields back.